# How to create users groups in Vanilla Forum

Tags: forum, usergroups, user-forums

i'm looking for a way to create users groups in [Vanilla Forum](http://vanillaforums.org/) (Vanilla is an open-source  community-building solution)

The goal is allowing users, registered in a certain group, reading and editing  only discussions created by users registered in the same group.

Example:

```
 Group 1 Users --> read & write only in Group 1 Discussions.
 Group 2 Users --> read & write only in Group 2 Discussions. 
 ....
 Group N Users --> read & write only in Group N Discussions.
```

Someone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Forums uses a system called "Roles and Permissions" to manage access rights for groups of users. You'll find the Roles and Permissions link in your Dashboard (specifically, /dashboard/role).

When you create a category, you can assign it custom permissions for each defined Role in your application, allowing you to exclude some people but allow others in, either to post, read, or both.